# How to create shared AdMob to be displayed in all ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, admob

I am trying to configure a single ad for all the bannerViews inside the app.

On AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var adBannerView = GADBannerView() // Create our one ADBannerView

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx")

        // Set delegate and hide banner initially
        adBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxx"
        adBannerView.delegate = self
        adBannerView.clipsToBounds = true
        adBannerView.load(GADRequest())
        adBannerView.isHidden = true

        return true
    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        adBannerView.isHidden = false
    }

    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        adBannerView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Inside ViewControllers `viewDidLoad()`, I call below function:

```
func addBannerToView() {
    appDelegate.adBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
    appDelegate.adBannerView.rootViewController = self
    appDelegate.adBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                                            y: view.frame.height - appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.height,
                                            width: view.frame.width,
                                            height: appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.height)
    view.addSubview(appDelegate.adBannerView)
}
```

But I am getting below error:

> -Google- You must set the rootViewController property of -GADBannerView: 0x7fed29701d70; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = -CALayer: 0x6080000296c0-- before loading a request.

Comment: I have done this in the past, but in the end I removed the code. I succeeded but it was too complicated to do. I had issues with it but I cannot remember what they were. It was a waste of my time, I showed less impressions so got paid less by Google as well.
In the end I went with keep it simple, I have different banner views inside each view. It works. It isn't worth the effort to maintain the single bannerview, users don't care and I didn't want my app crashing. All that matters is users are happy and Admob is happy. Just do separate ones in each view, keep it simple , save your time.

Comment: @PeterSmith I actually figured this without any pain. Forgot to post it here. I am creating single ad request and adding it into global banner view. and then I am displaying it as subview on the all the views I like to. You think that will be problematic? I am about to submit the app to AppStore.